# VirtualBox Guest Additions installation on Kali Linux problem

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I've installed Kali Linux on VirtualBox, host is MacOS. When i'm trying to execute `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` command I get the following text:

```
    Verifying archive integrity... All good.
    Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.22 Guest Additions for Linux...........
    VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
    Removing installed version 5.1.22 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
    Copying additional installer modules ...
    Installing additional modules ...
    vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
    Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file
    /var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log for details.
```

In `/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log` I get the following:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd.service.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: modprobe vboxguest failed.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-x11.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-x11.service.
```

And in the `vboxadd-install.log` I get this:

```
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:112: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add any relevant information from `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log`.

Comment: '/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:112: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.' here it is

Comment: It looks like the build is not finding kernel sources/headers.  Can you try running `apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y` in your kali linux installation?

Comment: If you're using Kali 4.2 or higher, you can install the guest addition directly with apt: `apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Carpette](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/83944/carpette) you can install the guest additions on a Kali Linux >=4.2 guest by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
sudo reboot -f
```

Please see the [official instructions provided by the Kali Linux project](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-kali/) for details. This page also contains instructions for older Kali Linux versions.